# Powershell how to find idle time (mouse and keyboard, not processes) of another user on the network?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to use powershell to find out how long a user has been without any input from a mouse or keyboard.
I have tried:
Invoke-Command -Computername XXXX  -ScriptBlock {Write-Host ("Idle for " + [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime)}

However, it seems to start calculating Idle time from when the command was first run.  But the only way that would be useful is if we had it constantly running, which isn't good when we have a lot of computers.

Is there any way using Powershell I could do this?

Maybe my method of finding the info could be improved?  As currently I have been using New-PSSession and Get-CimInstance